# Where can I use the Configratuion Class in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

i am new to symfony Bundle System.

And i am reading this:

> http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/configuration.html

So after i am done in all the configuration whats next?

I mean where can i used all those configuration in my application?

I dont really understand where those values from the config.yml goes after configuration.

Can someone explain what will happen next?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Build an application using Symfony? or use components from the Symfony framework? Build a bundle? Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These values will be stored in the container automatically.

**If you have this configuration:**

```
// src/Acme/SocialBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php
namespace Acme\SocialBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('acme_social');

        $rootNode
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('twitter')
                    ->children()
                        ->integerNode('client_id')->end()
                        ->scalarNode('client_secret')->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end() // twitter
            ->end()
        ;

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

**You can read it from your controller like this:**

```
$client_id = $this->container->getParameter('acme_social.twitter.client_id');
$client_secret = $this->container->getParameter('acme_social.twitter.client_secret');
```

Comment: Thanks =) so that becomes parameters value? Therefore can use it on my services?